# How to compare the results between decomposition and SARIMA for a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, prediction, decomposition

I was asked in an exercise to compare the results of function `decompose` and the model SARIMA. I only know to plot the results of function `decompose`

[image]

and the prediction of model SARIMA

[image]

Could you please elaborate on some aspects for which I can compare them?

```
Y = scan('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Time-Series/main/trafic.dat')
Y = ts(Y, start = 1963, frequency = 12)
X = window(Y, end = 1979 + 11/12)

# Decomposition
Z <- decompose(X)
plot(Z)

# Fit a SARIMA model
res <- arima(X, order = c(0, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))
library(forecast)
plot(forecast(res, h = 12, level = 95), include = 12)
lines(tail(Y, 12))
legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("Prediction", "Actual Data"), col = c(4, 1), lty = c(1, 1))
```